# Wireless Lan RALINK RT5370 not working

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, ralink

I am new to Linux. Would appreciate if you can help me with the below problem.

I have a wireless lan - RALINK. When I run the lsusb command, following is the output.

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

During the first boot after the install, the wlan worked. However, after subsequent boots, the Wlan (network mgr) shows the WLAN (home wifi) but is unable to connect.

I was reading through various web resource and finally followed the following steps as described in one of the posts.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218445&page=2

I executed the following steps

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
wget media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/13/16/4365112-Ralink_5370sta-2.5.0.3_dkms.tar.gz
sudo tar xvf 4365112-Ralink_5370sta-2.5.0.3_dkms.tar.gz -C /usr/src
sudo dkms add -m Ralink_5370sta -v 2.5.0.3
sudo dkms build -m Ralink_5370sta -v 2.5.0.3
sudo dkms install -m Ralink_5370sta -v 2.5.0.3 
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA
sudo cp /usr/src/Ralink_5370sta-2.5.0.3/src/RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA 
echo "blacklist rt2800usb" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

However, the issue still persists. I think earlier, iwconfig command used to show more entries, but now says no wireless extensions. Appreciate any help here.

Comment: wget media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/13/16/4365112-Ralink_5370sta-2.5.0.3_dkms.tar.gz

^^ File is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help for someone,
I had a issue with rt5370 wifi dongle, it did not work properly, but somehow I managed to fixed it.

Open the terminal:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/95-RT5370.rules
```

A new empty document will open. Copy and paste the text as follows:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="148f", ATTR{idProduct}=="5370", RUN="/etc/RT5370.sh"
```

Save and close gedit Create another file:

```
gksu gedit /etc/RT5370.sh
```

A new empty document will open. Copy and paste the text as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
modprobe rt2800usb
echo 148F 5370 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id
```

Save and close `gedit`

make the file executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/RT5370.sh
```

Go to super user mode:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/xiangzhai/rt5370.git
cd rt5370/
make
make install
echo rt5370sta >> /etc/modules
```

Unplug the wifi usb dongle

Reboot the machine and plug the wifi usb dongle

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 it does not compile. I tried applying [patch](https://github.com/agerwick/RT28XX-RT539X-Linux-driver/pull/11/commits/42146a862acd3ade152faee55a5d81df6bc441b4) and it fixed some of the errors, but then more errors from cmm_mac_usb.c popped.